# Cannot fetch data from AWS Lambda service with ESP32 HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, aws-lambda, esp32, arduino-esp8266

Can anyone tell me why I can't successfully create GET-request to my AWS Lambda-function with ESP32-microcontroller (Arduino C)?

- I created AWS Lambda service with Serverless framework.
- I have created python-script for Raspberry Pi that sends GET-request (get settings) to AWS Lambda and then RPI starts sending measurement data to that same API. And everything works fine.
- But now I'm trying to reproduce this functionality with ESP32 & Arduino C, but it's not working.

**Successfully created requests with following software:**

- Python-script with 'requests'-library
- NodeJS app with 'node-fetch'-library
- Postman
- VS code Rest-client extension
- Atom Rest-client extension

**Not working:**

- Arduino libs (HTTPClient.h || ArduinoHTTPClient.h)

So what are the differences between these ? Missing some header in GET-request ?

ESP32 gives following errors:

- -2 (Raw status code ?)
- send header failed (HTTPClient.h status code ENUM)

I used this guide when creating the ESP32 code:
https://medium.com/@sanghviyash6/migrating-any-http-request-to-https-on-esp32-5545a6de7845

What piece is missing from me that is built into all the other methods?

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
 
const char* ssid = "yourNetworkName";
const char* password =  "yourNetworkPass";
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
}
 
const char* root_ca= \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"BAUwAwEB/zAKBggqhkjOPQQDAwNoADBlAjEA7wNbeqy3eApyt4jf/7VGFAkK+qDm\n" \
"fQjGGoe9GKhzvSbKYAydzpmfz1wPMOG+FDHqAjAU9JM8SaczepBGR7NjfRObTrdv\n" \
"GDeAU/7dIOA1mjbRxwG55tzd8/8dLDoWV9mSOdY=\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
 
void loop() {
 
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
 
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("https://aws/function", root_ca); //Specify the URL and certificate
    int httpCode = http.GET(); //Make the request
 
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
 
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
 
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
 
    http.end(); //Free the resources
  }
 
  delay(10000);
}
```

Code above causes:

- httpCode: = -2

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Share code that demonstrates your problem and you might get some help. Otherwise you’re asking us to guess what you’re doing wrong.

Comment: You didnt read my post?

Comment: This:
https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/11/18/esp32-arduino-https-get-request/
not working with AWS Lambda function:
"https://someChars.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/myFunction"

Comment: I did read your post. Providing a [minimal, viable, complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that demonstrates the problem gives your post value to others who have similar issues. It also means that your question is still meaningful if the page you linked to goes away. And it means we're debugging code you actually ran, not looking at some example code that you copied and modified without telling us about the changes you made. If you want help, post code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [this HttpClient](https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient) library, then it expects to receive a WiFiClientSecure instance which implements the TLS layer.